# Asp.Net Core + SignalR + Https

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core, signalr

Доброго всем времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, застрял((

Установил SignalR, код на странице следующий

```
<script>
    let hubUrl = 'http://$ip/updater';
    let httpConnection = new signalR.HttpConnection(hubUrl);
    let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(httpConnection);
    hubConnection.start();

    hubConnection.on("Send", function (data) {
        location.reload();
    });

</script>
```

он мне на это говорит:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://$ip:44309/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://$ip/updater'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Хорошо, видимо надо тоже через HTTPS, указываю url: 'https://$ip/updater'

Ответ:

net::ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED, Error: Failed to start the connection. Error

Ошибка довольно немногословная, так что не очень понятно как это исправить.
Фаервол у меня отключен. Но сайт использует авторизацию на основе Identity, может дело в этом? Надо как-то настроить авторизацию для SignalR?

**UPD:**

Прошу прощения , это я туплю, достаточно написать вот так:

```
let httpConnection = new signalR.HttpConnection(
                        '/updater', 
                        { transport: signalR.TransportType.WebSockets});
```

**UPD2:**

Все это происходило при тестировании на локальной машине. А в бою при открытии страницы пишет мне вот так:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://$ip/updater?id=020c7e1d-53bd-43da-8c27-  c824a1c1b16d' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' 
header value
```

Решение - установить протокол WebSockets для IIS

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте решения в виде ответов,  а не в виде правок вопроса

Comment: Прошу прощения, я здесь новенький и еще не освоился